# how to set up a bootstrap 4 three column grid with fixed percentages

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, grid-layout

I have a fairly normal Bootstrap 4 grid, dividing a row into 3 columns with equal width:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

(or using the Bootstrap 4 autolayout feature I could remove the "-md-4" part.

However, now I need to adapt the layout, so that the middle column is half of the width of the first or the last column:

|  40 %  |20 %|  40 %  |

If I would use the standard 12-column grid system, that would not add up (I would have to introduce 1/10 columns?): 4,8 | 2,4 | 4,8

Is there an (easy) possibility to achieve that? Do I have to redefine the Less/Sass Variables for the amounts of available columns and their widths? (which I would rather not, since I quite like the original grid system) - I imagined if I had a 10/20/../10x Grid System, I could very easily build it:

```
<div class="row"><!--10 equal width columns-->
  <div class="col-md-4">col-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-2">col-2</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">col-4</div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: No, should not be possible. Either use the 10 of 12 columns or define a new grid system with CSS.

Comment: How precise do you need to handle it? One alternative could be to just use `col` for the 1st and 3rd column, and `col-md-*` for the center.  The outer columns would fill (evenly) to take up the remaining space.

Comment: @RobertC I thought about that, going first with a 5|2|5 layout before trying your approach with col|col-md-3|col however I need it exact (it's for an image grid where I want 2 images in the first columns, 1 in the middle and again 2 in the second and it would look odd if they were not the same width because then the proportions would be off)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way with Bootstrap "out-of-the-box", but you could extend use of the auto-layout (`.col`) columns by setting a specific width...

```
.col-20 {
    flex: 0 0 20%;
    max-width: 20%;
}
.col-40 {
    flex: 0 0 40%;
    max-width: 40%;
}


<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-40">col</div>
    <div class="col col-20">col</div>
    <div class="col col-40">col</div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/cCakaqk7UP

Comment: I'm going to use that, thank - for the previous "col-md-4" grid breakpoint I added a media-query for the newly created col-20/col-40 classes to display the columns properly on mobile devices